# How can we see if prerendered resource or prefetched resource is actually prerendered or prefetched on Firefox, Safari and IE10?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, prefetch, prerender

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML Document</title>
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://www.apple.com/">
<link rel="prerender" href="https://www.apple.com/">
```

Say we have codes above. https://www.apple.com/ is prerendered on Chrome. We can see this if we turn Chrome's Task manager on. This is pretty good.

How can I know if https://www.apple.com/ is actually prefetched on Firefox? Does Firefox provide a solution for this?

How can I know if https://www.apple.com/ is actually prefetched or prerendered on Safari and IE10? Do these 2 browsers provide solutions for this?

Thank you!

BTW. Which method do Safari and IE10 choose? Prerendering or prefetching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox you can have the cache clean and then whatch it by opening `about:cache`. I have done this for testing the `prefetch` directive and it worked preety well.

In Chrome you can go to `chrome://cache/`.

I am not aware if Safari and IE have implemented anything related to `<link rel="prefetch" ...>` hints.

Answer (score -1):

IE 11 has prerender implemented. you can also combine prefetch and prerender by giving `rel="prerender prefetch"`

This will be for all browsers but Safari is still mystery.